# Joins with a SELECT command

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

I have been looking and trying to join two tables to get one result but with no luck. (yes a newbie)

Here is the scenario:

**Table T1**

```
ID | t1_name | **t1_value**
```

**Table T2**

```
ID | t2_something | **t2_name** | t2_more | t2_etc
```

What I am trying to do is a `SELECT` query to get a result to ECHO the `t1_value`.

This is from **t2_name** equaling the same as **t1_name** then return the **t1_value** to ECHO.

These are based on each indivdual "t2 ID" (100 + ids) having its own result.

Im sure this is an easy solution, and all the reading and research I have done on joins i just cant seem to get my head around it. Maybe over reading....

If you can offer a solution/help, (with how it works so I can learn for next time)
That would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks to all of you guys for your quick response and links to the Join commands. The answers worked well and was good seeing different ways of going about the same option. A little more study on these and a bit more reading to get a bit more of an understanding of them. But your answers have made it a little easier since its relating to my project. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select t1.t1_value
from t1
inner join t2 on t1.t1_name=t2_name
```

For more study you can refer **[INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)**

And Different type of **[JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)**

A **[VISUAL REPRESENTATION OF JOIN](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)**

Answer (score 2):

[**`JOIN`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables with the condition `t1.t2_name = t2.t2_name`, then in the `SELECT` clause select whatever you want to select.

Something like:

```
SELECT
  t2.ID,
  t1.t1_value,
  ...
FROM t1
INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.t1_name = t2.t2_name;
```

You might also need to have a look at the different types of `JOIN`, see this for more information:

- [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select t1_value from T1, T2 where T1.t1_name = T2.t2_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1_name.t1, t2_name.t2 FROM t1, t2  WHERE t1.t1_name = t2.t2_name
```

That should work as expected, just to clarify you can also use `INNER JOIN` syntax as referenced here : http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by just joining two tables t1 and t2.

```
SELECT
      t1.Name,
      t1.value
FROM t1,t2 
WHERE t1.t1_name = t2.t2_name
```